# How to change app's display name in Titanium studio iPhone app?

Tags: titanium

Consider i have named my new titanium iphone project as `MyApp`.
So the name under my app icon displays as `MyApp`, now i want to change it to `MyApp1`.

How do i achieve this?

I tried renaming name tag in tiapp.xml file, but its not useful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that is how you change the name. After you edit the `tiapp.xml` name, Go to `Project > Clean` and select the project. Then rebuild. Another option is just to create a new project with the name you want and copying over the resources directory.